# Manga where mc dies and reincarnates into same world and body

Tags: story-identification, manga, cultivation, martial-arts

I'm looking for a manga where the main character is poisoned or injured by a relative or clan member, dies from it, but reincarnates into same body a couple months before he dies, and he goes hunting and searching for herbs while injured and manages to find or buy the herbs to heal himself and help his father get stronger as well. The start is similar to Eternal Reverence (Yong Heng Zhi Zun).

Comment: Given the mention of a clan member, is this a wuxia/cultivation story? Is it set on Earth? Another world? Modern times? Prehistory? Medieval times?

Comment: Its a cultiavtion story and not based in modern times i totally forgot to add that

Comment: Is [BLACKVEHETA's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/274286/122024) the one you're looking for?

Comment: No it isnt its different and from reading the description sounds like its modern day nothing like what im looking for

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is what you're looking for [Isekai Tensei... Saretenee!](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/uea1hsf/isekai-tensei-saretenee)

This story is about a teenage-boy who gets killed by accidently by God. So God decides he's going to reincarnate the boy into another world. But accidently reincarnates him into his old world with his old but new body and with spiritual powers. He can now see other people's spiritual moves and make them his own simply just by looking at the formula of the spiritual move and makes them far stronger than they originally was.

Comment: Can you expand on why this is a match?